# emplace_back error using struct with base class members?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20

In the following example, I have a base and derived struct, each with a single member, and a vector of the derived type. When I try to push_back to the vector, it works as expected. However, I get a compilation error when trying to use emplace_back.

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    int foo{};
};

struct Bar : public Foo
{
    int bar{};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Bar> barVec;
    
    // Works
    barVec.push_back({2, 3});
    
    // Doesn't work
    //barVec.emplace_back(2, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:518:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘construct_at(Bar*&, int, int)’
  518 |           std::construct_at(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);

...

/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_construct.h:96:17: error: could not convert ‘std::declval()’ from ‘int’ to ‘Foo’
   96 |     -> decltype(::new((void*)0) _Tp(std::declval<_Args>()...))
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 |
      |                 int
```

If I wrap the first argument as a `Foo` however, it works.

```
    // Works
    barVec.emplace_back(Foo{2}, 3);
```

I kind of understand what's going on (something about how `std::allocator_traits::construct` works) but I'm confused about the specifics. What are the steps that push_back and emplace_back take to construct the object, and why does the original emplace_back fail?

Comment: it doesn't have much to do with vector. `Bar b1(2,3);` fail, `Bar b2(Foo{2},3);` success.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. So it isn't something special about `std::allocator_traits::construct`, it's just a peculiarity when constructing this sort of class without an explicit constructor to handle calling the base class constructor.

Comment: `Bar b({2,3});` succeds. The point is that `push_back` uses values, while `emplace_back` tries to build an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesized aggregate initialization doesn't support brace elision. ([§dcl.init](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#17.6.2.2))

---

`Bar b1(2,3);` would fail.

`Bar b2(Foo(2),3)`,
`Bar b2(Foo{2},3)`,
`Bar b2({2},3)`* would success

---

*since there is no way to pass `{2}` (as *braced-init-list*) around, you cannot use it at `vector::emplace_back` either.

Comment: For completeness, what about `bar b2{2, 3}`?  I assume also failure?

Comment: @MooingDuck no, that would success (assume you mean `Bar`), it's also what happens at `barVec.push_back({2, 3});` in OP's code.

Comment: @MooingDuck the new parenthesized aggregate initialization (`()` instead of `{}`) added in c++20 has this difference.

Comment: fwiw, aggregate with base class is only  allowed since c++17.